# inserting multiple values into a single cell using sql 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the typical table:

```
LSRNbr  BatchNbr
111     1212
111     1414
```

And the query should return:

```
LSRNbr   BatchNbr
111      1212, 1414
```

I was browsing for a solution to this and I found these two:

**Solution 1:**

```
;WITH C AS 
(
SELECT LSRNbr, BatchNbr FROM tblDTS_LSRBatch
)

SELECT Distinct LSRNbr, 
STUFF((SELECT ';' + BatchNbr FROM tblDTS_LSRBatch WHERE LSRNbr = c.LSRNbr FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') 
FROM C
```

**error:**

```
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near ';'.
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Line 7: Incorrect syntax near 'XML'.
```

**Solution 2:**

```
SELECT 
[LSRNbr], REPLACE(RTRIM((SELECT [BatchNbr] + ' ' FROM tblDTS_LSRBatch WHERE (LSRNbr = Results.LSRNbr ) FOR XML PATH (''))),' ',', ') AS NameValues
FROM tblDTS_LSRBatch Results
GROUP BY LSRNbr
```

**error:**

```
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Line 2: Incorrect syntax near 'XML'.
```

But none of them worked for me, see errors above please.

What could be the problem here?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are syntax errors.

You'll learn more from figuring out the particular error yourself:

Take a look at the [syntax tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190922.aspx)

Take a look at some [good examples](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=createacommadelimitedlist) of [what you're trying to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

If you still have trouble, feel free to ask more questions

Comment: Perfect, I appreciate your help :)

Comment: is something related to my version of sql server, cause I did the same in sql 2008 and it works :(